# Angular 4 routing to external outlet

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I would like to know how to link to an outlet `(name="info")` from ANY component **without need to configuring the "info" outlet as a child in the router for each component**?

e.g. I have a side info column (with help information in it) OR a kind of shopping cart which lists all added items etc.

The outlet is defined in the app.component directly an if I try to link to it the from another component then the app itself it doesn't work.

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { side:['info']}}]">
SHOW INFO
</a>

<router-outlet name="side"></router-outlet>
```

router setting:

```
[...,
 { path: 'info', component: SomeInfoComponent, outlet: 'side'},
 { path: 'compa', component: AComponent}
]
```

The resulting URL finally is:

```
/anylink/(side:info)
```

instead of

```
/anylink(side:info)
```

EDIT:

OK... still doesn't works from component "from" an outlet:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { side:['info']}}]"> <!-- direct link -->
SHOW INFO
</a>

<comp-a></comp-a> <!-- static acomp -->

<a routerLink="/compa"> <!-- loaded acomp in std. outlet-->
SHOW COMPA
</a>    

<router-outlet name="side"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And inside the comp-a.html:

```
comp-a.html:

<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { side:['info']}}]">
SHOW INFO
</a>
```

Should that work anyway?

EDIT 2:

Router link to named outlet through standard router-outlet.

Now I see 3 `SHOW INFO` Links with these generated Info links:

- direct link: (generated link: `/anylink(side:info)`) -good
- static acomp link: (generated link: `/anylink(side:info)`) -good
- dynamic acomp in router-outlet (generated link: `/anylink/(side:info)`) -bad

And here you see my problem:

A component loaded inside the router-outlet generates the wrong link to the named router-outlet.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

... still unresolved problem

Comment: Your code is correct

Comment: Check the other routes, maybe You set routes like: `/anylink/`

Comment: Thanks, it realy work in that example. Please take a look at the EDIT part. This makes still problems

Comment: Yes it should work

Comment: did it help, let me know please :-|

Comment: I check it out and let you know :)

Comment: I will appreciate it :-|

Comment: Hey I checked it. See my edits. It doesnt work if I link from a router-outlet itself.

Comment: You don't need to hard code you route

Comment: ? What do you mean? Can you post a right example?

Comment: do hard coded this:  `(link: /anylink(side:info))` right?

Comment: If so You don't need to do that, You need to use the same link: `<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { side:['info']}}]">` +1

Comment: :) sry, this is my bad explanation. these links are the generated links by clicking "SHOW LINK"

Comment: ... still unresolved problem